# display table rows as boxes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```js
var empobj2=[{app:"new",comment:"sjkk",date:"02/10/2018"},{app:"new",comment:"sjkk",date:"02/10/2018"},{app:"new",comment:"sjkk",date:"02/10/2018"}];
```

```html
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
<thead style="background-color:#FDDDD2">   
<tr>
<th style="width:30%;text-align: center;">Appreciated To</th>
<th style="width:40%;text-align: center;">Comment</th>
<th style="width:30%;text-align: center;">Date Created</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>   
<tr ng-repeat="caserecord in empobj2" >
<td style="text-align:center;">{{caserecord.app}}</td>
<td style="text-align:justify;">{{caserecord.comment}}</td>
<td style="text-align:center;">{{caserecord.date}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hi, This is my code I want to display each row as a box. And between two rows some space should be there.Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
tbody > tr > td {
  padding-bottom: 10em;
}
```

Adjust value in em or px, whatever to a value you prefer.

If you need precisely for that table, try adding `id="idvalue"` to that `<table>`  and target like

```
#idvalue > tr > td {
  padding-bottom: 10em;
}
```

You can also use `padding-top` if you wanna start with the gap between 1st row and header row of table:

```
#idvalue > tr > td {
  padding-top: 10em;
}
```

**EDIT: Per comment, this is the new solution:**

change HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="blank">
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:center;">{{caserecord.app}}</td>
   <td style="text-align:justify;">{{caserecord.comment}}</td>
   <td style="text-align:center;">{{caserecord.date}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

add into your CSS:

```
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table tr {
  border: 5px solid brown;
}

.table .blank{
  height: 20px; 
  border: none;
}
```

Explanation: I added a blank row with no borders in front your `tbody` rows. Looks like empty space. Also I setup border on your other rows and header. You can customize those as you please.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOG4x.png  exactly I want to like this boxes.  Thanks for the answers